# docker agent option is invalid for a shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

`args` option for docker agent is invalid when I run pipeline which use a shared library.

```
Invalid config option "call" for agent type "docker". Valid config options are [image, alwaysPull, args, containerPerStageRoot, customWorkspace, label, registryCredentialsId, registryUrl, reuseNode] @ line 30, column 25.
                   args "-u root:root -v ${WORKSPACE}:${goPath}"
                   ^
```

If I commend the `args` option, it won't show this error. Other options such as `image` and `reuseNode` are working as expected.

I don't have the issue when I use it directly in the jenkinsfile without use shared library.

goTest.groovy

```
def call(){
      pipeline{
          stage('golang-install') {
                agent {
                    docker {
                        image 'SOME GOLANG IMAGE'
                        'args' "-u root:root -v ${WORKSPACE}:${goPath}"
                        reuseNode true
                    }
                }
                ...
           }
       }
   }
```

jenkinsfile use shared library

```
@Library('common-ci') _

goTest()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved. Because I setup the function parameter as args, it override the args as an option for docker. After change the input parameter name, issue is solved.
old one

```
def call(Map args) {

}
```

new one

```
def call(Map opts) {

}
```

Comment: Very dumb and obscure. As someone not familiar with Jenkins libs and Groovy, I would've missed that. Nice catch.